# MSSQL Operation within OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, operators

I am trying to join two tables using a unique value, however in one table it is part of a field with different lengths, e.g.:

Table one:

```
       Block_Run_No  Vehicle_No
200001.412.20110104        1001
 20002.412.20110104        1002
```

Table 2

```
Block_No  Departure
  200001       3600
   20002       7200
```

Now I want to join them by Block_No and try this:

```
SELECT Block_No, Vehicle_No, Departure
FROM Table1,
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 A on LEFT(Table1.Block_Run_No,CHARINDEX('.',Table1.Block_Run_No)-1) = A.Block_No
```

However, It claims to not recognize the expression `Table1.Block_Run_No` within the JOIN. Anyone can help me out here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH Table1( Block_Run_No,Vehicle_No) AS
(
SELECT '200001.412.20110104', 1001 UNION ALL
SELECT '20002.412.20110104', 1002
),Table2(Block_No, Departure) AS
(
SELECT 200001,3600 UNION ALL
SELECT 20002,7200
)

SELECT Block_No, Vehicle_No, Departure
FROM Table1
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 A on 
    LEFT(Table1.Block_Run_No,CHARINDEX('.',Table1.Block_Run_No)-1) = A.Block_No
```

Works fine for me. You have a rogue comma here

```
FROM Table1, FULL OUTER JOIN
```

Maybe that's the source of the complaint? (Intellisense complains that `Table1.Block_Run_No` cannot be bound until this is removed but also red underlines `FULL`)

Comment: Awww, of course. I labored hours and did not find the stupid comma.. Thanks!